# How to add a new form to the Jobeet example?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I did the [Symfony 1.4 Jobeet example project](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/) and now i would like add an additional form.

How to do it correctly in a single project? Default Symfony itself generates the first form, but how can I create my own from scratch?

If i use in command line:

```
php symfony doctrine:build --forms
```

This generates only the default form, I would like to have two forms. How can I do it? Must I generate a new project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not need to create a new project. You can extend your test project by adding an additional form class. Just do [like you did for your first form](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/10), but give it another classname and place it into a file of it's own.

You can do this test-wise by copying over your existing form file and rename both the filename and the classname.

Comment: copy file in: ||
/lib/model/JobeetJobForm.class.php ||
/lib/form/base/BaseJobeetJobForm.class.php ||
/apps/frontend/modules/job/templates/_form.php ||
/apps/frontend/modules/job/templates/newSuccess.php
?? Is that all?

Comment: My fault Patrick, I've seen you would like to get the forms file generated by doctrine. Do you want that? Or do you want to create an additional form manually? - In any case, you do not need to create a new project, only because you need a new form.

Comment: dummy. I would simply have 2 forms in one module :) the best generated by Doctrine

Comment: Okay, Doctrine generates the form based on you database model. So if you extend your database model and run the command from your question, the new form(s) will be generated.