# where is model for default generated form?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

i generated new project and new module with Jobeet http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/03
where is the model for this form? i would like show how this is add or edit in database?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the [section about forms in the Jobeet tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/10). It has the list of the locations on disk. It explains it better than I could, so I just link it. Also see this question: [How to add a new form to the Jobeet example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321786/how-to-add-a-new-form-to-the-jobeet-example) for some more information.

Comment: I would like to edit the form generated by default. It is not widget and validators. i will methods in model for this form

Comment: See the section **Customizing the Job Form** in the link above. It explains where you find the file and how to do that.

Comment: it isnt it. there isn't for example add to database. i want to the model (insert into, delete, update etc) this form.

Comment: So you need additional functions on the model (not the form)?

Comment: But what exactly do you want to do? I still have problems to find out what you're looking for.

Comment: i want to see how adding to the database using the generated form. for example will make in token + 'test'

Comment: simply where is model this form? in what file?

Comment: there is only JobeetJobForm.class.php. i dont see methods instert into, update, delete etc

Comment: These methods are part of the model classes, not the form classes. You need to look for the model classes then.